# Operator Overloading Tricks in C++

Tags: c++, overloading

This method is taken from [Syntactic Aspartame](http://www.curly-brace.com/Aspartame.html). This is my attempt at a generic version.

The goal is to create an operator `X <NAME> Y` where name is anything, and X, Y, and the return is of any type.

Here is the 'library':

```
#ifndef COMPUTERSCIENCE_ANGULAR_OPERATOR_H
#define COMPUTERSCIENCE_ANGULAR_OPERATOR_H

template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET> struct AngularOperator;

template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET>
struct InnerAngularOperator {
    const AngularOperator<LHS, RHS, RET>* outer;
    LHS* lhs;
    bool outer_l;

    RET operator>(RHS& rhs) {
        return (outer_l) ? outer->angular_lr(*lhs, rhs) : outer->angular_rr(*lhs, rhs);
    }

    RET operator<(RHS& rhs) {
        return (outer_l) ? outer->angular_ll(*lhs, rhs) : outer->angular_rl(*lhs, rhs);
    }
};

template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET>
struct AngularOperator {
    explicit AngularOperator() { }

    virtual RET operator()(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs) const = 0;
    virtual RET angular_lr(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs) const { return operator()(lhs, rhs); }
    virtual RET angular_rr(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs) const { return operator()(lhs, rhs); }
    virtual RET angular_ll(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs) const { return operator()(lhs, rhs); }
    virtual RET angular_rl(LHS& lhs, RHS& rhs) const { return operator()(lhs, rhs); }
};

template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET>
InnerAngularOperator<LHS, RHS, RET> operator<(LHS& lhs, const AngularOperator<LHS, RHS, RET>& outer) {
    return {&outer, &lhs, true};
};

template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET>
InnerAngularOperator<LHS, RHS, RET> operator>(LHS& lhs, const AngularOperator<LHS, RHS, RET>& outer) {
    return {&outer, &lhs, false};
};

#endif //COMPUTERSCIENCE_ANGULAR_OPERATOR_H
```

And here is a simple implementation for string concatenation:

```
static const struct OP__ANG__STRING_CONCAT : AngularOperator<std::string, std::string, std::string> {
    std::string operator()(std::string& lhs, std::string& rhs) const override { return lhs + rhs; }
} C{};
```

And finally the usage of all of this would be:

```
std::string a = "123", b = "456";
std::string c = a <C> b;
// c == "123456
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your approach is problematic, in the following senses:

- You use inheritance for genericity. There's no good reason for there to be an abstract base class for such operations. The behavior of your class is compile-time-determined by the binary operator you which to represent, and nothing else.
- You use virtual methods, which really have no bearing on the problem at hand. That is, I don't see any reason why such operators need vtables.
- You template on the binary operator's parameter and result types, rather than the operator itself, i.e. instead of

  ```
  template <typename LHS, typename RHS, typename RET>
  ```

  try

  ```
  template <typename Function>
  ```

  with `std::return_type` to obtain `RET` and so on.
- Your infix operator implementation has state - and pointer state at that, which is difficult to optimize away - instead of just using temporary values which can get discarded. Don't be so stuck on imperative programming...

I'm pretty sure you could address all three of these issues with a more templated-oriented implementation; with an intermediate class for "infix operator after having gotten the LHS" (or after having gotten the RHS) which can then take the other operator. Possibly the [CRTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173254/what-is-the-curiously-recurring-template-pattern-crtp?s=5%7C68.8949) is relevant here.

I'm being a bit brief and a bit philosophical since I'm strapped for time. If this is too vague for you (=OP), ask for clarification and I'll expand this answer later on.

Comment: I know this is little late, but could you elaborate on the four bullet points. I understand the last one pretty well, but the others are more... shaky. Thanks, Zach.

Comment: @ZachHilman: Added a few words.